# ActionScript 3 - adding gradient to object

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, matrix, gradient

I have an instance of a MovieClip called 'BlueBox', which is just a 'Drawing Object' which is blue. It is inside a container called 'option1MC' which is inside 'option1Container' which is on the stage.. It's color can be changed like so:

```
option1Container.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, option1ContainerOver);

var optionOver:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
optionOver.color = 0xC56516;

function option1ContainerOver(evt:Event):void {
    option1Container.option1MC.BlueBox.transform.colorTransform = optionOver;
}
```

I want to change the color to a gradient. This is what I tried:

```
var mtr:Matrix = new Matrix();
mtr.createGradientBox(option1Container.option1MC.BlueBox.width, option1Container.option1MC.BlueBox.height, 0, 0, 0);
mtr.graphics.beginGradientFill(GradientType.LINEAR, [0xFF0000, 0x0000FF], [1, 1], [0x00, 0xFF], mtr); 
mtr.graphics.drawRect(0,0,option1Container.option1MC.BlueBox.width, option1Container.option1MC.BlueBox.height);
```

However, right now when I run the .fla file, it i giving me an error saying:

```
Access of possible undefined property graphics through a reference with static type flasg.geom:Matrix:
```

and is referring to the lines

```
mtr.graphics.beginGradientFill(GradientType.LINEAR, [0xFF0000, 0x0000FF], [1, 1], [0x00, 0xFF], mtr); 
mtr.graphics.drawRect(0,0,option1Container.option1MC.BlueBox.width, option1Container.option1MC.BlueBox.height);
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Because a `Matrix` is not a `DisplayObject` with a `graphics` member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Matrix` does not have a `graphics` property. You would need to apply this to a `DisplayObject` with a `graphics` property. That would look something like this with your setup:

```
//create the sprite to do the gradient fill on or use your MovieClip
//var spriteObject:Sprite = new Sprite() or just use option1Container;

//enter your matrix
var mtr:Matrix = new Matrix(); 
mtr.createGradientBox(option1Container.BlueBox.width, option1Container.BlueBox.height, 0, 0, 0);

//apply it to the sprite
sprite.graphics.beginGradientFill("linear", [0xFF0000, 0x0000FF], [1, 1], [0x00, 0xFF], mtr); 
sprite.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 40); 
sprite.graphics.endFill(); 
addChild(sprite);
```

I created a sprite variable here, which is not necessary as you can just swap `sprite` with `option1Container`

You can reference adobe's help for this as well: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7dd7.html

Now if you drew the `MovieClip` graphics in the IDE you won't currently be able to change it. In which case you can create a new `MovieClip` and add it to your container like so:

```
//note I made a target variable just to save on typing:
var target:MovieClip = option1Container.option1MC.BlueBox;
var gradientLayer:MovieClip = new MovieClip();

var gradientBox:Matrix = new Matrix(); 
gradientBox.createGradientBox(target.width, target.height, 0, 0, 0); 
gradientLayer.graphics.beginGradientFill("linear", [0xFF0000, 0x0000FF], [1, 1], [0x00, 0xFF], gradientBox); 
gradientLayer.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, target.width, target.height); 
gradientLayer.graphics.endFill(); 

//giving the asset a name will allow you to easily remove it later
gradientLayer.name = "gradientLayer";

target.addChild(gradientLayer);
```

Notice I gave the gradient asset a name of "gradientLayer". If you want to remove this child later on you can do that with:

```
option1Container.option1MC.BlueBox.removeChild( option1Container.option1MC.BlueBox.getChildByName( "gradientLayer" ) );
```

Comment: hm, option1Container is already on the state, so I don't need to do addChild(option1Container) right? For some reason, when I do "option1Container.graphics.beginGradientFill("linear", [0xFF0000, 0x0000FF], [1, 1], [0x00, 0xFF], mtr); 
option1Container.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 40); 
option1Container.graphics.endFill(); " It does not change the color of the blue box inside the movieclip. I also tried doing 'option1Container.BlueBox.graphics' but that didn't change it's color either. Any idea why?

Comment: Without actually looking at your setup I'm not sure why it would not be working. The code I provided is correct and a working example when `spriteObject` is a `new Sprite()` or `new MovieClip();` and also works properly if I add a child onto the sprite and apply the graphics properties.

Comment: hm, okay suppose on the stage there is a movieclip called 'option1Container', inside that, there is a movieclip called 'option1MC' and inside that, there is a movieclip called 'BlueBox' which is an instance of a rectangle with rounded edges, drawn out in flash and converted to a movieclip placed in the library. To change BlueBox's color from blue, I would do "option1Container.option1MC.BlueBox.transform.colorTransform = optionOver;" (given that optionOver is a color transform).. would you know how to change the color of BlueBox from a color to a gradient?

Comment: Ah I see the issue, I'll add it into my answer.